# What would be a suitable textbook of first semester physical chemistry?

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations, physical-chemistry

I am going to take PChem I in my biochem dept next sem, which is a watered down version of the PChem course in Chem dept. It basically covers thermodynamics and a little bit of quantum stuff. The syllabus says there is no required text, since course notes will be available once we register for class. But I do want to get ahead of class by reading books. I have several books at hand, please give me suggestions on which one should I use and if you have any good free lectures, feel free to post links as well

Intro to Molecular thermodynamics by Hanson&Green, PChem for Chem and BioSci by Chang,Molecular Driving Forces by Dill&Bromberg, PChem: A molecular approach by McQuarrie, An introduction to thermal physics by Schroeder,Pchem by castellan, Callen's thermodynamics text and also Fermi's

Personally, I found Hanson, Castellan, Dill, and Chang are pretty good, haven't read any other